# sort a Dict on alphabet by name in python

Tags: python

Have a dict with values(string)- name and number's (int).

I want the dict to be sorted by name.

Have:

```
sorted(dictList, key = lambda (k,v): v['name'])
```

But get - "string indices must be intergers, not str".

```
def to_dict(lstData) :
    dct = dict();
    for dctData in lstData :
        dct[dctData['id']] = dctData['name'];
    return dct;


Units = to_dict(db.getUnits());
sorted(Units, key = lambda k: Units[k]['name']);
```

If I run-
sorted(dctunits, key= lambda x:x[1])

I get: `'long' object is unsubscriptable`.

It is sorting on wrong value. 
in (x=1L)

```
builtin sorted = <built-in function sorted>, 
global dctUnits = {1L: 'kg', 2L: 'day', 3L: 'week', 
     4L:  'month', 5L: 'g/L', 6L: 'ug/dL', 7L: 'ng/mL', 
     8L: 'year', 9L: 'min/day', 10L: 'cm', ...}, 
key undefined, 
x = 1L
```

X should be 'Kg'..

What is that I'm are missing?

Comment: show us yourdata structure, you said it's a dictionary but you call it `dictList`

Comment: so you want to sort a list of dicts by their names?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using (all of it) Input (sample) data, and what output/error you are getting, and what you expect to get.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing your Lambda wrong, You can either sort the dictionaries keys, or its values, or sort by the key value pairs.

(assuming `dict` is your dictionary)

By keys:

```
sorted(dict.keys(), key=lambda k: dict[k]['name'])
# will return a list of the keys, sorted by the value of 'name'
```

By values:

```
sorted(dict.values(), key=lambda v: v['name'])
# will return a list of the values, sorted by the value of 'name'
```

By pairs:

```
sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v['name'])
# will return a list of the key value pairs, sorted by the value of 'name'
```

Comment: `dictList` must already contain the result of `dict.items()`, otherwise the exception would be `ValueError`: need more than 1 value to unpack.

Comment: This won't work because `dictList` is obviously not a dictionary (see err message)

Comment: @jamylak I have a feeling the OP simply named their dictionary "dictList" because they are novices. +lvc , or dictList has 2 items, in which case the second item (v) is a key and he is tring to access it using string indices? Without more code it is not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code you have provided gives me the original error rather than the new one. There's a couple of things to notice about why it does this - first, what the error is telling you is that parts of a string are accessed strictly this way:

```
>>> 'abc'[1]
'b'
```

rather than this way:

```
>>> 'abc'['b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

The reason it is trying to do this is because when you do in your key function:

```
Units[k]['name']
```

`Units[k]` resolves to `Units[1L]`, which resolves to the string `'kg'`. You can't ask that string for its `['name']`, since that doesn't make sense for strings. Probably what you are trying to do is sort by the values (what you're thinking of as the 'name', even though you haven't told Python that's what it is), in which case you want something like:

```
>>> sorted(Units, key=lambda k: Units[k])
[10L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 8L]
```

You can avoid the lambda by realising that dictionaries already have a method to do that it is doing - `sorted(Units, key=Units.get)` will achieve the same thing.

Also, some general comments on your code that aren't directly related to the problem:

- Python doesn't require you to end each line with `;`, and convention is that you omit it even though it is *allowed*
- The 'L' at the end of all your numbers is likewise a no-op (effectively - it changes stuff you don't need to care about), and is forbidden in Python 3
- Your `dctUnits` appears to already be a dict; I can't quite tell what your `to_dict` function is meant to be doing (the way I read it, you should be getting a different error much sooner), but it seems to be completely unneeded.

Comment: How hard should it be to sort a list/dict...
Now I'm trying to sort the LstData in my to_dict func.
There I have the object unit in a list... but it seems not work there either.
Any ideas?

Comment: @kingRauk it is as easy as calling `sorted` with an appropriate key function (if you don't want the natural ordering). Your problem is *entirely* that your key function doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: But what is a appropriate key function? Have tried everything on google now... hopeless. Missing C# :-(

Comment: .. I gave two (equivalent) key functions in my answer, as well as explaining why yours doesn't work. If these don't do what you want, you should edit your expected output in to the question and ask for it to be reopened.